# Drupal 7: how to relate between 2 exposed filter, when one work stop the other?

Tags: views

I have two unrelated exposed filters in my view, one are completion for the other but in another design, like this:

[image]

and I want one filter work every click, which mean when click 'computer', only computer result  will display ,then when click 'physics', only physics result will be display .. so How can i stop one when the other work???

thank you

Comment: did u look for `OR` in views filter settings?

Comment: yes I try it, when I click computer then click physics .. the result display computer and physics because in this case the query is (computer or physics)  and that mean both, but what i need just what i click on it .. thank you